# convert dynamic table into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, spacebars

I have a table that updates dynamic (thank you to those who helped with my last publish/subscription inquiry) and I would like to store the data of each updated row into an array which I will then insert into a mongodb collection. My Table is as follows:

```
<template name="choral">
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 25px">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <form id="orderForm">
    <table id ="productList" class="table table-borderless table-dark">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Title:</th>
            <th>See the Music:</th>
            <th>Hear the Music:</th>
            <th>Format:</th>
            <th>Price (per copy):</th>
            <th>Quantity:</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {{#each pieces}}
        <tr id="itemList">
            <td id="name">{{name}}</td>
            <td id="pdf">PDF</td>
            <td id="audio">AUDIO</td>
            <td id="format">FORMAT</td>
            <td id="price">{{score}}</td>
            <td id="qty"><input type ="number" name ="quantity"></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <td><button id ="#addItems" class="button" type ="submit">Add to Cart</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
  </table>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to pull the data from each row in the body of the table and store the dynamic data into an array. something like this:

```
Template.choral.events({
'click #addItems': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cartItem =[];

    $('#itemList tr').each(function(){
        var item = [];
        var name = $('#name',this).val();
        var price = $('#price',this).val();
        var qty = $('#qty',this).val();
            item.push({name, price, qty});
            cartItem.push([item]);
    });
    console.log(cartItem)
}
```

});

I don't know if this idea works when a table is populated via spacebars calls to helpers or if this is even valid use of .each(). Ultimately, the end result of these queries should result in this:

```
cartItems [{name1, price1, qty},{name2, price2, qty}]
```

Comment: You should not produce identical `id` attributes in HTML. It is invalid. Use a `class` attribute instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't produce identical `id` properties in the generated HTML -- that is invalid. Use `class` instead, like this:

```
    {{#each pieces}}
    <tr class="itemList">
        <td class="name">{{name}}</td>
```

... etc.

Secondly, the jQuery selector `$('#itemList tr')` is not selecting anything because `#itemList` does not *contain* any `tr` descendants, but is instead *itself* a `tr`. So together with the previous remark, the selector should be `$('tr.itemList')`.

Then, in your jQuery code select by class attribute (using `.`) and do it within the `this` context, so you match only within the current row:

```
var cartItem =[];

$('tr.itemList').each(function() {
    var name = $('.name', this).val();
    var price = +$('.price', this).val(); // convert to number?
    var qty = +$('.qty', this).val(); // (idem)
    var item = {name, price, qty}; // just assign to item
    cartItem.push(item); // don't use square brackets here
});
```

You might want the price and qty to be converted to numbers. In that case use the unary `+` (see above).

I don't think you want `item` to be an array, but just the object with the three properties.

Notice also the fix in the `push` argument.

Comment: still getting cartItem is undefined. I changed the initial $('.itemList tr') using class rather than id.

Comment: Indeed, that selector is wrong. I have added a paragraph about that in my answer with a fix: `$('tr.itemList')`. Also, where in your code do you get `carItem` is undefined?

Comment: I've updated the js code a bit to more reflect what I'm going for. This table is serving as essentially my product inventory and then, once I set this squared away, will insert into a shoppingCart Collection. Posted my update

Comment: Hold on; I see you have updated the code in your question which now uses class selectors. You should not do that. Now my answer looks stupid. Please put back the code as you originally had it in your question. You can *add* a new section to your question if you wish, but don't keep extending the question. Keep it to your original question. Ask an entirely new question if you have additional needs.

Comment: BTW, the `do` loop which you now include in your question (and which was not there at first) does not make a lot of sense. It will not work for several reasons.

Comment: Is the code in my answer giving you the content in the `cartItem` array? I am still at a loss where you got the error that `cartItem` is undefined? Could you point out which line of code is producing that error?

Comment: No, your code doesn't produce an error I mispoke, I tried to pull the value of the array using console.log but the button just refreshes the page on click

Comment: OK, but that is a different issue: a button in a form will *submit* that form unless you cancel that effect (or just don't use the `form` tag at all).

Comment: Okay, took the form element away and tried to click the button, no effect and no insertion into the array. Console.log doesnt fire

Comment: I cannot reproduce that non-effect. Could you create a runnable snippet?

Comment: I changed the click event to recognize class rather than id and the event fired. Have new issue now so I will ask another question but thank you for your help with this